# Custom Scalar Valued function in Hibernate 5.x

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a custom Scalar Valued function in SQL with the below details:

- Name : **fn_WorkDays**
- Returns : **Int**
- Parameters : 1. **StartDate** (type - datetime) 2. **EndDate** (type - datetime)

I'm using Hibernate 5.4.6 to fetch some records from the database. I want to use the above function in the HQL (in the Where Clause), however currently facing issues.

```
Query<Device> query = session.createQuery("Select ud from Device ud where fn_WorkDays(ua.created, current_date())>2",   Device.class);
```

After going through some posts, I understand that the custom function needs to be registered before using it, hence have created the below class:

```
public class MySQLServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect {
    public MySQLServerDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("fn_WorkDays", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "fn_WorkDays(", ",", ")"));
    }
}
```

Have updated the hibernate.cfg.xml with :

```
<property name="dialect">com.test.service.utils.MySQLServerDialect</property>
```

I dont seem to understand how the registerFunction should be done as im getting the below error:
**ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:142 - 'fn_WorkDays' is not a recognized function name.**

Log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n" />
        </Console>      
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- Log everything in hibernate -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>

        <!-- Log SQL statements -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />           
        </Logger>

        <!-- Log JDBC bind parameters -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />           
        </Logger>

        <!-- Log custom packages -->
        <Logger name="com.test.service" level="debug"   additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />           
        </Logger>

        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Any help to resolve the above will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:142 - 'fn_WorkDays' is not a recognized function name.

The error already says what is wrong, the function does not exist in the database.

Try this:

```
registerFunction("fn_WorkDays", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "dbo.fn_WorkDays(", ",", ")"));
```

Comment: The function does exist in the database, im able to use it in the sql query. But just finding it difficult to use with HQL. Given the above details about the function (fn_WorkDays), what is the correct way to register it?

Comment: Maybe this is case sensitive? Or maybe the function is located in a different schema and you need to fully qualify it.

Comment: I have run "select objectproperty(object_id('fn_WorkDays'), 'IsSchemaBound')" and got result as 0. Im using the same database is used in hibernation connection url. Can you advice if 
registerFunction("fn_WorkDays", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "fn_WorkDays(", ",", ")")); 
is correct for the function having 2 datetime parameters and int as result.

Comment: It's correct like you did it. Like I wrote, the error you are seeing comes from the database so I think that the function does not exist in that schema you are using. Can you update your question and post the full stack trace?

Comment: Updated the stack trace

Comment: What you posted is not a stacktrace. I need to see where the exception comes from and also see what it is, the database complains about. Maybe the issue is that you are trying to bind values of the wrong type for the bundleId predicate.

Comment: Entire stack trace was too big to fit, hence have just added the last lines which could fit in

Comment: I bet when you execute this query with your query editor you have somekind of predefined schema search path or run this with a different user than your main workload. AFAIU SQL Server tries to find the function in the default schema and if not found, looks into the `dbo` schema. The error clearly states that this happens on the DB side so it must be some kind of namespacing issue.

Comment: Found the issue. The correct query should be:
Query<Device> query = session.createQuery("Select ud from Device ud where dbo.fn_WorkDays(ua.created, current_date())>2",   Device.class); the dbo. was added and it worked which seems strange as it should have looked in it.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that are not pre-defined in the JPQL/HQL are invoked like this:

```
`function('fn_WorkDays' , ua.created, current_date())`
```

This is later translated to `fn_WorkDays(ua.created, current_date())` in the native query. You still need to have it registered by the dialect as you have.

Comment: That's not true, you can directly use `fn_WorkDays(ua.created, current_date())`.